# Upload .xlsx, .xls, .csv file

Tags: r, shiny

I currently am able to upload a .csv file but when I try to upload a .xlsx or .xls file I receive an error.
"Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/var/folders/k7/s4xbp26d059b_sm6q08hl5mm0000gn/T//Rtmp6mzvQO/de97a3667d0706ae06136c4b/0.xlsx'"

This is currently what I have.

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)


population <- read.xlsx("population.xlsx", 1)


fieldsMandatory <- c("selectedCountry", "modelSelect", "seedData")

labelMandatory <- function(label) {
  tagList(
    label,
    span("*", class = "mandatory_star")
  )
}

appCSS <-
  ".mandatory_star {color: red;}"

appCSS <- ".invisible {display:none;}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  div(
    class = "invisible",
    titlePanel("Spatial Tracking of COVID-19 using Mathematical Models")
  ),
  
  navbarPage(title = span("Spatial Tracking of COVID-19 using Mathematical Models", style = "color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:15pt"),
             
             tabPanel(title = "Model",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                              fileInput("seedData", labelMandatory ("Upload initial seed data (.csv or .xls or .xlsx)"),
                                        accept = c(
                                          "text/csv",
                                          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                          ".csv",
                                          ".xls",
                                          ".xlsx"),
                              ),
             
                        ), 
                        mainPanel(
          
                            tabPanel("Initial Seed Data",
                                     tableOutput("tableSeed")),
                            
                         
                          )
                        )
                        
                       
                      )
             )
             
             
             
  )


server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: `read.table` expects csv or txt.  You may need packages for `.xlsx` i.e. `read_excel` (readxl) or `read.excel` (from `xlsx)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have downloaded the xlsx package and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: ok, your code is not reproducible for testing

Comment: I have updated the code to be testable

Comment: When I copied your code, it says `upload complete` for xlsx or csv.  The server part in your code is empty

Comment: I see the issue in my code, in my server it says "read.csv" but I assume it should also have another function that has read.excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115854/r-shiny-csv-or-excel-upload-option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since reading excel data and csv data requires different function you can extract the extension from the filepath and use the function accordingly.

This might help -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("seedData", "Upload initial seed data (.csv or .xls or .xlsx)",
            accept = c(
              "text/csv",
              "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
              ".csv",
              ".xls",
              ".xlsx")
  ),
  tableOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$seedData)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$seedData$datapath)
    if(ext == 'xlsx')
      readxl::read_excel(input$seedData$datapath)
    else 
      read.csv(input$seedData$datapath)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(data())
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```